# How can I get the PinchZoom ended event in Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, zooming, scrollviewer, pinchzoom

I'm using XAML with C#.
I have an Image in a ScrollViewer that is Zoomable.
If the user pinchzooms the image, I want to get a larger resolution image once the optical zooming is done  and replace it with the lower resolution zoomed image.
I don't want to get a larger image for every event captured. Only when the user is done zooming.
Hope this is clear. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Hook up to the ViewChanged event of the scroll viewer, then when the event is fired, check for e.IsIntermediate in the ScrollViewerIsViewChangedEventArgs.

e.g:

```
private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if(!e.IsIntermediate)
  {
    //Load new image depending on the zoom factor
  }
}
```

It ISN'T intermediate when the user is done pinch zooming.